# Dynamically set div postion and size in JS - how to make the transition smoother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the position and size of four divs dynamically. Using `position:relative;` to set the top and left in the CSS or `display: inline-block` will not work for my situation. I have other elements that will get skewed and not look right if not done this way. I have it so that it sets everything in the correct position, but the transition from one position to another as well as one width to another doesn't happen as smooth as I would like. I don't want it to happen in steps like it does now, I need it to happen all at once, unfortunately I need the setTimeout function for this to work properly, but that is what causes the delay. If anybody could help me get a really nice transition when the button is clicked, (immediate & all at once) I would really appreciate it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcolbert/bqstws6z/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button id='button'>
    Click here
  </button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <label class="label">Title</label>
    <label class="percentage">93%</label>
    <label class="difference">3%</label>
    <label class="more">...</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <label class="label">Title</label>
    <label class="percentage">96%</label>
    <label class="difference">3%</label>
    <label class="more">...</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <label class="label">Title</label>
    <label class="percentage">91%</label>
    <label class="difference">1%</label>
    <label class="more">...</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <label class="label">Title</label>
    <label class="percentage">92%</label>
    <label class="difference">5%</label>
    <label class="more">...</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  setSizes();
  setPosition();

  $('#button').click(function() {
    if ($('.container').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.container').removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.container').addClass('active');
    }

    setSizes();
    setPosition();
  });

  function setSizes() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      setBoxSizes();
    }, 250);
  }

  function setBoxSizes() {
    var box = $('.box'),
      difference = $('.difference'),
      percentage = $('.percentage'),
      more = $('.more');

    for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      $(box[i]).animate({
        width: (($('.container').width() - 118) / box.length) + 'px'
      }, 300);
      $(difference[i]).animate({
        left: (((($('.container').width()) / box.length) - (($(difference[i]).width() + $(percentage[i]).width())) + 55) - 105) + 'px'
      }, 300);
      $(more[i]).animate({
        left: (((($('.container').width()) / box.length) - (($(difference[i]).width() + $(percentage[i]).width())) + 20) - 105) + 'px'
      }, 300);
    }
  }

  function setPosition() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      setBoxPosition();
    }, 1000);
  }

  function setBoxPosition() {
    var box = $('.box'),
      top = 0,
      left = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
      $(box[i]).animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 200);
      $(box[i]).css('top', top + 'px');
      $(box[i]).css('left', left + 'px');

      top -= 120;
      left += ($(box[i]).width() + 22);
    }
  }
```

CSS

```
 .box {
  width: 414px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px #888;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.percentage {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.difference {
  position: relative;
  left: 260px;
  top: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.difference::after {
  content: '\25b2';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.more {
  font-size: 28px;
  position: relative;
  top: -55px;
  left: 230px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}

.container {
  width: 1800px;
}

.container.active {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet from your code.

Comment: @connexo I'm not sure what you mean. I have included a JSFiddle, followed by the code in that fiddle.

Comment: @ThomasColbert if you will use position:absolute then top & left will works and also if you want to make smother transition effect then just increase the time (for eg. 300 -> 500).

Comment: @MaulikBhatt if I use position: absolute, it won't work. I need it then to appear right next to each other and change widths, if I use display: inline-block it will not work either, as it pushes them into the wrong position and the delay causes the page to look bad before adjusting with js. I need it to be able to change positions when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Using top & left to position block elements, mixing JQuery and HTML5 animations... geez. I want to see your webpage to understand why your layout is like this and not inline-block while just changing the percentage width, or flexbox.

The main problem here is line

```
 left += ($(box[i]).width() + 22);
```

depends on the previous JQuery animation being completed since it depends on the final width. This means you can't have the instant switch you want doing your method. You'll have to hard-code the value by calculating it in the previous function, and knowing that the width animation takes 300ms time it for that.

Also you should change your css to

```
 transition: left .3s ease
```

cause your width change is delayed extra because of it.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqstws6z/9/)

Still looks a bit jank due to no interaction between the elements.